# postgresql Select higher Timestamp with Null Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem is if i compare two timestamps and one of them is NULL it chooses Null as higher Value.

```
SELECT case 
         when "Date1" < "Date2" then "Date1" 
         else "Date2"  
       end as "HigherDate"
FROM "table"
```

How can i select always the higher date between those two even if one of them is NULL?

Comment: You are probably abusing NULL to mean "infinity". Instead use `'infinity'` or `'-infinity'`, which are valid values for timestamps in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `greatest()` which is NULL safe:

```
select greatest(date1, date2) as higher_date
from the_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use COALESCE.

SELECT case when COALESCE("Date1", ConstantLowerDate) < COALESCE("Date2", ConstantHigherDate) then "Date1" else "Date2" end as "HigherDate" FROM "table"

Where ConstantLowerDate is a fixed date always lower what all Date2 possible values and ConstantHigherDate always high what Date1.
Attention: If Date1 and Date2 are null will return ConstantLowerDate

Comment: I tried it with  COALESCE it worked as well. But the solution above is easy and works.